# JupyterHub starting notebook progress doesn't work with 403 error (stopping server also produce 403)

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub

We have JupyterHub installed in k8s cluster with authentication through KeyCloak. JupyterHub is installed by jupyterhub Helm chart version 2.0.0 from https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart repository.

When a user is authenticated and run a server the page with message "Your server is starting up. You will be redirected automatically when it's ready for you." doesn't show any progress and hub logs the following error: **Action is not authorized with current scopes; requires any of [read:servers]"**

Full log is:

```
[I 2023-01-11 16:41:08.977 JupyterHub app:2775] Running JupyterHub version 3.0.0
[I 2023-01-11 16:41:08.978 JupyterHub app:2805] Using Authenticator: oauthenticator.generic.GenericOAuthenticator-15.1.0
[I 2023-01-11 16:41:08.978 JupyterHub app:2805] Using Spawner: kubespawner.spawner.KubeSpawner-4.2.0
[I 2023-01-11 16:41:08.978 JupyterHub app:2805] Using Proxy: jupyterhub.proxy.ConfigurableHTTPProxy-3.0.0
[I 2023-01-11 16:41:09.049 JupyterHub roles:183] Role attribute user.scopes has been changed
[I 2023-01-11 16:41:09.061 JupyterHub app:1934] Not using allowed_users. Any authenticated user will be allowed.
...
...
...
[W 2023-01-11 16:41:44.763 JupyterHub base:89] Blocking Cross Origin API request.  Referer: https://styx-dev.themodelvault.com/hub/spawn-pending/stasdavydov, Host: styx-dev.themodelvault.com, Host URL: http://styx-dev.themodelvault.com/hub/
[W 2023-01-11 16:41:44.763 JupyterHub scopes:804] Not authorizing access to /hub/api/users/stasdavydov/server/progress. Requires any of [read:servers], not derived from scopes []
[W 2023-01-11 16:41:44.763 JupyterHub web:1796] 403 GET /hub/api/users/stasdavydov/server/progress (::ffff:10.0.138.202): Action is not authorized with current scopes; requires any of [read:servers]
[W 2023-01-11 16:41:44.766 JupyterHub log:186] 403 GET /hub/api/users/stasdavydov/server/progress (@::ffff:10.0.138.202) 4.57ms
```

The same problem happen when stop the server: **API request failed (403): Action is not authorized with current scopes; requires any of [delete:servers]**.

UPD: I found similar problem explained but didn't see a solution: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/cross-origin-issue-upgrading-from-1-5/15428

Appreciate for any suggestions about how to fix.

Comment: The problem for me seems to be more related to CORS. I think you need to start your jupyter hub with https://github.com/twosigma/beakerx/issues/1963#issuecomment-481044822

Comment: @behanzin777 Good point, but I don't understand how to set the suggested parameters with Helm chart (we use jupyterhub v 2.0.0 from https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart). I don't see correspondent parameters in the chart values.

Comment: What about this https://github.com/jupyterhub/binderhub/blob/31149279def7e0183c6b4be76a7b1e5b1d016361/testing/local-binder-k8s-hub/jupyterhub-chart-config.yaml#L13 ?

Comment: @behanzin777 it is for BinderHub spawner, we don't have it in our environment.

Comment: @NataliyaLeLoup yes, but by downgrading version of JupyterHub chart to 1.2.0 -- it's working well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, the problem is resolved by downgrading JupyterHub chart version to 1.2.0.